# How to deploy my simple Anglular app in Facebook

Tags: angular, facebook, rest, webhooks

I have created a simple app using `Angular 4` which will enable users to take some quizzes. I need the user to get an option to post the result on his wall after the completion of the quiz and also get the user data when the user tries to play the quiz. I would also like to provide the user with the option to share this app with the friends.

The app is still not deployed and I am accessing it using the `http://localhost:4200` URL. I was trying to post this app in my developer account to view the app and then set up REST calls to post the user data to my application.

My first concern is, even after creating an adding an app, I am still unable to find an option to view the app on Facebook. Is there any good documentation, that would address beginners to create and post an app on Facebook.

I followed the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register and few similar docs. But these do not address all the steps and not helpful for beginners.

Comment: How to view the app on Facebook, depends on what platform you are using. Assuming it's "Web Games", it is `https://apps.facebook.com/` followed by either app id or app namespace. The app dashboard section for the platform settings also explicitly shows it.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for the update, can I still use an application in the localhost URL and view the app in facebook in my machine

Comment: You'll need an SSL cert and use HTTPS. A self-signed certificate will do, as long as you can bring your browser to accept it first - otherwise it will just be blocked from loading into the iframe, since the parent page was accessed via HTTPS. And to avoid problems with cookie acceptance etc., I would recommend to set up a local test domain other than `localhost`, such as `myapp.local`, and use HTTPS default port 443.

Comment: @CBroe, so the first thing I need to do would be deploy the app, may be in aws and then try to set up using the facebook developer account, right, in that case how can I configure things like getting the ser data when a person try to play the game or posting on the wall, sharing with friends etc

Comment: Now that is way too broad for one question, and deserves your own proper attempt at researching the necessary details first.